# Explicit formula for Hermite polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-writing

We have the Hermite polynomials:

$$H_n(t)=(-1)^ne^{t^2}\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left(e^{-t^2}\right),\quad n=1,2,\dots.\tag 1$$ My problem is writing $H_n$ from $(1)$ as follows:

$$H_n(t)=n!\sum_{j=0}^N(-1)^j\frac{2^{n-2j}}{j!(n-2j)!}t^{n-2j}\tag2,$$
where $N=n/2$ if $n$ is even and $N=(n-1)/2$ if $n$ is odd.

I tried to use the Leibniz rule for the product, but I can't solve. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I'm confused with the question? Are you trying to establish the second equation from the first equation?

Comment: @CheeHanYes, sorry! Now I correct. Please, help me!

Comment: [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) should also work with $f(x)=\mathrm{e}^x$ and $g(x)=-x^2$. Note that $g^{(j)}(x)=0$ for $j\ge 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of the exponential function we know that for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$ there exists a polynomial $p_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that:
$$
\frac{d^n}{dt^n}e^{-t^2}=p_n(t)e^{-t^2}
$$
Moreover the $p_n$ satisfy the following recursive definition
$$
p_{n+1}(t)=p_n'(t)-2tp_n(t)\qquad\text{and}\qquad p_0(t)\equiv 1\tag3
$$
as is readily verified by induction:
\begin{align*}
p_{n+1}(t)e^{-t^2}=\frac{d^{n+1}}{dt^{n+1}}e^{-t^2}=\frac{d}{dt}(p_n(t)e^{-t^2})&=p_n'(t)e^{-t^2}+p_n(t)(-2t)e^{-t^2}\\
&=(p_n'(t)-2tp_n(t))e^{-t^2}
\end{align*}
for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$.
With this tool at hand proving that your equation (1) implies (2) is equivalent to showing that
$$
p_n(t)=(-1)^nn!\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}2\rfloor}(-1)^j\frac{2^{n-2j}}{j!(n-2j)!}t^{n-2j}\tag4
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$, $t\in\mathbb R$. Now are you able to prove (4) via induction, using (3)?